# comparing and extracting elements of 2 nested loops in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, nested-loops

I have two 2d arrays.

```
a=['the flower is red','butterflies are pretty','dog is a man best friend']
b=['231','01','034']
```

Array `a` contains sentences, while array `b` is the indexes of the word that I would like to extract from array `a`.
For example by comparing the individual elements in `b[0]` which is `231`, I would like to extract `is`,`red`,`flower` where as for `b[2]`, I would like to extract `dog`, `man`,`best`.

So, in order to do that, I have to elements `a[]` word by word, and then compare with each of the individual elements in `b[]` (for example to read `2`,`3`,`1` individually to compare with the index in `a[i][j]`.)

Hence, I would require two 2d array loops and compare them.   [ 4 for loops I think]

```
for i in a:
    x= i.split()
    #x=one word
        for idx, word in enumerate(x):
            #idx= index of one word, word=one word
            for i in b:
                for y in i:
                    if y == idx: #comparing y which is a number with the index in a[]
                    print(word)
```

the code above is incorrect somehow and i don't know what or where went wrong.
So, what is the code to get the wanted result?

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for idx, s in enumerate(b):
    r = []
    for c in s:
        r.append(a[idx].split()[int(c)])
    print r
```

Comment: i've tried this code, and it is almost the result that i am looking for. however, is it possible to code it back into their original indexes as a[]?

for example:
result=['is red flower','butterflies are','dog man best']   (note that the words are not tokenised but instead combied back to be one sentence in one index)

Comment: @Lily I'm afraid I don't understand your question; could you post the expected result?

Comment: i want the result to be in the form of array, without losing it's original index n the array.
 result=['is red flower','butterflies are','dog man best']
 (note that the words are not tokenised but instead combied back to be one sentence in one index)

Comment: Alrighty, thank you so much for your help @memo. It's amazing how  you can code in a much simpler way instead of long blocks like what i did.